# Close all open Google Maps InfoBoxes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infobox

I've tried a few things I've found here on StackOverflow, and I'm not having any luck with this. I'm pretty rusty on my Javascript, so I wouldn't be surprised if it's something super simple to make this work.

I'm building a Google Map system for a website, and I am using the infoBox system so that I can have more control over the visual style of the popups. My problem is that I only want one infoBox open at any given moment. So as soon as 1 marker is clicked, the previous infoBox should close. I know the best method is to track what's the last one to be opened, but with the loop being used to build everything, I'm not sure how to grab the instance name of a specific infoBox to use the close() function.

Here's my Javascript:

```
    var map;
    var markers = new Array();

    // This function builds out the Google Map
    function initialize() {

        // Set the center point of the map to be create
        var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(40.0378755, -76.3055144);

        // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add to the map type control.
        // This is where we specify the UI settings for the map.
        var mapOptions = {
            center: mapCenter,
            zoom: 8,
            disableDefaultUI: false,
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            scaleControlOptions: {position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM},
            streetViewControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        };

        // Draw the map on-screen.
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    };

    // This function creates pins for the map.
    var descriptionBox;
    (function () {

      google.maps.Map.prototype.markers = new Array();

      google.maps.Map.prototype.addMarker = function(marker) {
        this.markers[this.markers.length] = marker;
      };

    })();

    //This function builds the locations and information for the markers and infoboxes
    function showOverlays() {

        //Set data for individual marker
        var a = new Array();
            var t =  new Object();
        t.name = "Alert at this Location"
        t.desc = "Here's a brief description."
        t.lat =  40.3178755
        t.lng =  -75.9155144
        t.icon = "low"
        a[0] = t;

//Set data for individual marker
var t =  new Object();
t.name = "Moderate priority Issue Here."
t.desc = "Read this text."
t.lat =  40.4178755
t.lng =  -75.8155144
t.icon = "mid"
a[1] = t;

//Set data for individual marker
var t =  new Object();
t.name = "HIGH PRIORITY!"
t.desc = "This is some text"
t.lat =  40.5178755
t.lng =  -75.4155144
t.icon = "high"
a[2] = t;

//Set data for individual marker
var t =  new Object();
t.name = "Another Mid Alert"
t.desc = "Description would go here. This is a longer description to show how it would be handled."
t.lat =  39.4178755
t.lng =  -77.4155144
t.icon = "mid"
a[3] = t;

//Set data for individual marker
var t =  new Object();
t.name = "ALERT!!! READ ME!"
t.desc = "More Text Here"
t.lat =  40.3178755
t.lng =  -76.3155144
t.icon = "high"
a[4] = t;

//Gather the data for each individual marker, and put the data in a usable format.  
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(a[i].lat, a[i].lng);
    var markerIcon = a[i].icon;
    var heading = a[i].name;
    var description = a[i].desc;
    var infoContent = "<h1>"+heading+"</h1><p>"+description+"</p>";
    map.addMarker(createMarker(a[i].name,latlng,markerIcon,infoContent));
 }

//Builds and places the markers on the map.     
function createMarker(name, latlng, icon, infoContent) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map, icon: "images/"+markerIcon+"_icon.png"});
//Create event listener to know when a marker is clicked on.
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
  var descriptionBox
  descriptionBox = new InfoBox();
  //Settings for the infoBox
  var myOptions = {
            content: infoContent
            ,boxClass: "myInfoBoxStyle"
            ,disableAutoPan: false
            ,maxWidth: 0
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 0)
            ,zIndex: null
            ,closeBoxMargin: "2px 2px 2px 2px"
            ,closeBoxURL: "images/close.gif"
            ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false
            };
          //Close any open boxes
          descriptionBox.close();
          //Create new infoBox instance
          descriptionBox = new InfoBox(myOptions);
          //Draw infoBox on the map.
          descriptionBox.open(map, marker);
        });
        return marker;
      };
    };
```

There is a button that is clicked that calls the showOverlays(); function to display the markers on the map.

So what am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Create InfoWindows for Multiple Markers in a For loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355249/how-to-create-infowindows-for-multiple-markers-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the InfoBox. I'm more familiar with the InfoWindow but I believe they are very similar.

It looks like you are creating a new InfoBox in each marker click listener:

```
var descriptionBox;
descriptionBox = new InfoBox();
```

Instead, declare the InfoBox outside the click listener:

```
var infoBox= new google.maps.InfoBox({ content: 'hello world' });
```

And refer to it inside the click listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    infoBox.open(map, this);
    ...
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338349/infobox-with-infowindow-behaviours) for further info...

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
var infowindows = new Array();
var popup = new InfoBox({
  // size: new google.maps.Size(420,130),
    content:content_info
   ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-200, -241)
   ,disableAutoPan: false
   ,closeBoxMargin: "5px 5px 2px 2px"
   ,boxStyle: {opacity: 0.95
              }

});
infowindows.push(popup); //push all infoboxes to an array

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    close_popups();    //close any infobox open
    map.panTo(mycenter1);
    popup.open(map, marker);


    // currentPopup = null;
  });

function close_popups(){
  for(var i = 0; i<infowindows.length; i++){
    infowindows[i].close();
  }
}
```